# Is there some method to construct value for record with lenses without underscore identifiers?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

For example I have the following record

```
data Rec = Rec
    { _a :: Int
    , _b :: Int
    , _c :: Int
    } deriving (Show, Eq)

makeLenses ''Rec
```

and I see only 2 ways to constuct new values:

- `Rec{_a=1,_b=2,_c=3}`
- `Rec 1 2 3`

The second variant does not look good if the number of record fields is more than a pair and underscores does not look natural in the first one.

Are there any other ways to construct record values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that makes sense for your type, a [`Default`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-default-class-0.0.1/docs/Data-Default-Class.html) instance might be a good approach. Then you can do

```
   def & a.~1
       . b.~2
       . c.~3
```

Comment: Yes, just forgot this option. Though it's a bit long from my POV. But why do you write `($def)` and not `def`?